# activeTab permission issue for Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm running the following code in a background.js script for my Chrome extension:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(captureCurrentTab());

function handleCapture(stream) {
  console.log('content captured');
  console.log("backround.js stream: ", stream);
  alert(stream);

  // localStream = stream; // used by RTCPeerConnection addStream();
  // initialize(); // start signalling and peer connection process
}

function captureCurrentTab() {
  console.log('reqeusted current tab');
  chrome.tabs.query({active : true}, function(tab) {
      console.log('got current tab');

      chrome.tabCapture.capture({
          audio : true,
          video : false
      }, handleCapture);
  });
}
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> Unchecked `runtime.lastError` while running `tabCapture.capture`: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured.

However, I specifically am granting activeTab permission in manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "tabCapture",
    "activeTab",
 ]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11):

When the [`activeTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission is declared, you only get access to the current tab when a user performs certain actions that imply they want you to have access.

> The following user gestures enable activeTab:
>
> - Executing a browser action
> - Executing a page action
> - Executing a context menu item
> - Executing a keyboard shortcut from the commands API
> - Accepting a suggestion from the omnibox API

The error is telling you that capture the current tab because the user hasn't performed one of the actions listed above.

It looks like you might already understand this and just have an error in your code. When registering `captureCurrentTab` as the click listener for the browser action, you are actually executing it immediately instead of passing the function by reference. Change your first line to this:

```
// Remove the () after captureCurrentTab
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(captureCurrentTab);
```

Comment: That is the real problem. `captureCurrentTab` running at the time of initialization by mistake.

Answer (score 5):

`Chrome pages cannot be captured.` means that you are trying to capture a `chrome://`, `chrome-extension://`, or similar Chrome specific page which is not allowed. Make sure the current page is `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: This statement is true, but it would be more helpful if you also explain why "the current page" is such an URL. There are a few glaring issues in the question's code that cause this error.

Comment: if I am running a script like this in the background.js, how I can retrieve the active tab in javascript so the capture command happens in the context of that page?

Comment: just for others having this issue, this error appears if you have opened the inspector window for the background.js script at the moment of the invocation of the capture method.